# Tasks and align* environments baseline alignment

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, labels, tasks

In the example below, I want to raise the equations in `align*` environment, so they would be in the same line with the numbering labels of `Tasks` package. How I can do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,247mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,tasks}
\newcommand\dotfillin[1][4cm]{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}
\settasks{label=(\alph*),label-width=18pt,label-align=right,item-indent=23pt,label-offset=7pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task 
        \begin{align*}
            307 \times 8 & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
                         & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
                         & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
                         & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
        \end{align*}
    \task
        \begin{align*}
            208 \times 99 & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
                          & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
                          & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
                          & =\dotfillin[3cm]\\
        \end{align*}
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to change `\newcommand\dotfillin[1][4cm]{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}` to `\newcommand\dotfillin[1][4cm]{\raisebox{-2pt}{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}}`; by lowering the dots by `2pt`, one may create the impression that the dots are just below the baseline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may achieve your formatting goal by replacing the `{align*}` environments with `{aligned}[t]` environments. Just be sure to place the `aligned` environments in inline-math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,247mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,tasks}
\newcommand\dotfillin[1][3cm]{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}
\settasks{label=(\alph*), label-width=18pt, label-align=right,
          item-indent=23pt, label-offset=7pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task 
\quad$\begin{aligned}[t]
            307 \times 8 &= \dotfillin \\
                         &= \dotfillin \\
                         &= \dotfillin \\
                         &= \dotfillin 
      \end{aligned}$
\task
\quad$\begin{aligned}[t]
            208 \times 99 &= \dotfillin \\
                          &= \dotfillin \\
                          &= \dotfillin \\
                          &= \dotfillin 
      \end{aligned}$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```